# How to add spacing between headers in an ExpansionPanelList?

Tags: flutter, material-design, customization

I am new to flutter, and struggling somewhat with the flutter way of styling (never thought I'd say this, but I miss css). I made an ExpansionPanelList and I want to add spacing between headers so that I get something more like this: 
[image: spaced headers]

instead of having all the headers pressed together like this [image: unspaced headers]

While I'm at it, I'd like to add a box shadow to the headers, too (basically, I want them to look exactly like the first image). Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I tried adding padding to the header constructor, but this just made the whole header bigger, and did not add any space between headers (which makes sense in retrospect).

Here's my current code (pretty much just a boilerplate list)

```
Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      initialOpenPanelValue: null,
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded){
        widget.store.toggleExpandable(index);
        if(widget.store.expandables.contains(true)){
          if(!widget.store.fullView){
            ExpandNotification(expand: true)..dispatch(context);
            widget.store.toggleView();
          }
        }
        else{
          if(widget.store.fullView){
            ExpandNotification(expand: false)..dispatch(context);
            widget.store.toggleView();
          }
        }

      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: item.id,
            canTapOnHeader: true,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.headerValue),
              );
            },
            body: ListTile(
                title: Text(item.expandedValue),
                subtitle: Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _data.removeWhere((currentItem) => item == currentItem);
                  });
                }));
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey, @gollyzoom, did you find the solution, I am still stuck on this thing. It will be very helpful If can give me the solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Add a Divider() with a given height in the return of headerBuilder...